# Implement minhash LSH using Spark (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, minhash

this is quite long, and I am sorry about this.

I have been trying to implement the Minhash LSH algorithm discussed in [chapter 3](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3.pdf) by using Spark (Java). I am using a toy problem like this:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|element | doc0 | doc1 | doc2 | doc3 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|   d    |   1  |  0   |  1   |  1   |
|   c    |   0  |  1   |  0   |  1   |
|   a    |   1  |  0   |  0   |  1   |
|   b    |   0  |  0   |  1   |  0   |
|   e    |   0  |  0   |  1   |  0   |  
+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

the goal is to identify, among these four documents (`doc0`,`doc1`,`doc2` and `doc3`), which documents are similar to each other. And obviously, the only possible candidate pair would be `doc0` and `doc3`.

Using Spark's support, generating the following "characteristic matrix" is as far as I can reach at this point:

```
+----+---------+-------------------------+
|key |value    |vector                   |
+----+---------+-------------------------+
|key0|[a, d]   |(5,[0,2],[1.0,1.0])      |
|key1|[c]      |(5,[1],[1.0])            |
|key2|[b, d, e]|(5,[0,3,4],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|key3|[a, c, d]|(5,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+----+---------+-------------------------+
```

and here is the code snippets:

```
CountVectorizer vectorizer = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("value").setOutputCol("vector").setBinary(false);
Dataset<Row> matrixDoc = vectorizer.fit(df).transform(df);

MinHashLSH mh = new MinHashLSH()
  .setNumHashTables(5)
  .setInputCol("vector")
  .setOutputCol("hashes");

MinHashLSHModel model = mh.fit(matrixDoc);
```

Now, there seems to be two main calls on the `MinHashLSHModel model` that one can use: `model.approxSimilarityJoin(...)` and `model.approxNearestNeighbors(...)`. Examples about using these two calls are here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#lsh-algorithms

On the other hand, `model.approxSimilarityJoin(...)` requires us to join two datasets, and I have only one dataset which has 4 documents and I would like to figure out which ones in these four are similar to each other, so I don't have a second dataset to join... Just to try it out, I actually joined my only dataset with itself. Based on the result, seems like `model.approxSimilarityJoin(...)` just did a pair-wise Jaccard calculation, and I don't see any impact by changing the number of Hash functions etc, left me wondering about where exactly the minhash signature was calculated and where the band/row partition has happened...

The other call, `model.approxNearestNeighbors(...)`, actually asks a comparison point, and then the model will identify the nearest neighbor(s) to this given point... Obviously, this is not what I wanted either, since I have four toy documents, and I don't have an extra reference point.

I am running out of ideas, so I went ahead implemented my own version of the algorithm, using Spark APIs, but **not** much support from `MinHashLSHModel model`, which really made me feel bad. I am thinking I must have missed something... ??

I would love to hear any thoughts, really wish to solve the mystery.

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

- The minHash signatures calculation happens in
  `model.approxSimilarityJoin(...)` itself where `model.transform(...)`
  function is called on each of the input datasets and hash signatures
  are calculated before joining them and doing a pair-wise jaccard
  distance calculation. So, the impact of changing the number of hash
  functions can be seen here.
- In `model.approxNearestNeighbors(...)`,
  the impact of the same can be seen while creating the model using
  `minHash.fit(...)` function in which `transform(...)` is called on
  the input dataset.